# HTML onclick event not working with innerHTML syntax for creating the button in the cell

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have this code which should insert a button in a table cell. The button has action so I add `onclick`. However, the syntax for `onclick='function_name'` is with single quotes. I used single quotes with/without backslash, but nothing solved the error I'm getting. I get `editRow is not defined` and pressing the button has no effect. I also found that the HTML is interpreting the single quote I entered in the text of the cell as double quotes. I do not know what is the source of the problem.

```
var info = [{
  "firstName": "aaa",
  "lastName": "A"
}, {
  "firstName": "bbb",
  "lastName": "B"
}, {
  "firstName": "ccc",
  "lastName": "C"
}];
function display(info) {
var table=document.getElementById("table");
var Length=info.length;

for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++)
{
    var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                            
    cell1.innerHTML = info.[i].firstName;
    cell2.innerHTML = info.[i].lastName;
    
    var editButtonHTML = "<input type=button value=Edit class=edit id=edit-button"+(i+1)+" onclick=\'editRow("+(i+1)+")\'>";
    
    cell3.innerHTML=editButtonHTML;
}//end for  

function editRow()
{
    console.log("inside editRow "+(i+1));
}

//console.log(table.innerHTML);
}//end display
```

The solution provided by @Rohit Kumar works when running the code in Firefox browser. But when running it in the addon extension using jpm, it gives:

> ReferenceError: editRow is not defined

Also, when I print the HTML code in the table, I see double quotation not single.

I also tried this after the button but did not work. The `getElement` returns null.

```
butId="edit-button"+(i+1);
    console.log("button id is: "+butId);
    
    document.getElementById(butId).addEventListener('click',editRow);
```

Comment: Have created a snippet, please check.

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) is this about ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) [[tag:firefox-webextensions]] or [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-sdk]]? They are *not* the same thing, but you have added both tags to your question. Please [edit] your question so it has only the ***one*** appropriate tag for the type of extension you are writing.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a *complete*, but minimal, [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your example when you are adding DOM element as a string, on click you are calling 'editRow' function in global (window) context.

What you should do is to create element, bind context with needed parameters and append it as a child DOM element:

```
var editButtonHTML = document.createElement('input');
editButtonHTML.type = 'button';
editButtonHTML.value = 'Edit';
editButtonHTML.className = 'edit';
editButtonHTML.id = 'edit-button' + (i+1);
editButtonHTML.onclick = editRow.bind(this, i + 1);
cell3.appendChild(editButtonHTML);
```

Here is full solution:

```
var info = [{
  "firstName": "aaa",
  "lastName": "A"
}, {
  "firstName": "bbb",
  "lastName": "B"
}, {
  "firstName": "ccc",
  "lastName": "C"
}];

function display(info) {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var Length = info.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
      var row = table.insertRow(i);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

      cell1.innerHTML = info[i].firstName;
      cell2.innerHTML = info[i].lastName;

      var editButtonHTML = document.createElement('input');
      editButtonHTML.type = 'button';
      editButtonHTML.value = 'Edit';
      editButtonHTML.className = 'edit';
      editButtonHTML.id = 'edit-button' + (i + 1);
      editButtonHTML.onclick = editRow.bind(this, i + 1);
      cell3.appendChild(editButtonHTML);
  }

  function editRow(num){
      console.log('inside editRow ' + num);
  }
}

display(info);
```

Comment: I have seen the edit.
Could you please leave a comment if you tried my solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem with the code was**

1. Initially the object info was not defined.
2. The edit method was wrongly called, it show the same message whatever button you click upon.
3. It was returning "inside editRow 4" though row no 4 never existed. "inside editRow 4" was created using the last I value of the for loop.
4. Also check if a blank tr tag is defined inside the table. Else row.insertRow function wouldn't work.

```js
var info = [{
  "firstName": "aaa",
  "lastName": "A"
}, {
  "firstName": "bbb",
  "lastName": "B"
}, {
  "firstName": "ccc",
  "lastName": "C"
}];
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var storageLength = info.length;

for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  var row = table.insertRow(i + 1);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  cell1.innerHTML = info[i].firstName;
  cell2.innerHTML = info[i].lastName;

  var editButtonHTML = "<input type=button value=Edit class=edit id=edit-button" + (i + 1) + " onclick=\'editRow(" + (i + 1) + ")\'>";

  cell3.innerHTML = editButtonHTML;
} //end for
   //Made an edit here
function editRow(rowindex)
{
    console.log("inside editRow "+(rowindex));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border='1'>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is identical to that in the question, isn't it?

Comment: ...one can pretty safely assume that `var table=document.getElementById("table");` is retrieving the table tag, even though that wasn't shown in the question.

Comment: OK.  Answers that are just code dumps without any explanation are not very helpful; you're leaving readers to guess what you changed and why you think it might answer the question.

Comment: @Rohit Kumar I tested you code in Firefox browser. It works fine. However, I use this HTML page in addon extension panel. It shows me the same error. Wehn I printed the HTML code that was generated, I find onclick srrounded by double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You should swap your use of single quotes and double quotes so that the string editButtonHTML is surrounded by single quotes, and the HTML within the string uses double quotes around all of the tag attributes.

```
rowNumber = i+1;
var editButtonHTML = '<input type="button" value="Edit" class="edit" id="edit-button"'+ rowNumber +' onclick="editRow(' + rowNumber + ')">';
```

That said, you might want to reconsider outputting HTML directly as a string and instead attach a new button object to the DOM using jQuery to create the button, set the tag attributes, and define the onclick event action.

Comment: Can you explain the jQuery method with code? I do not know about this.

Comment: also, your solution did not make any different. I run it and the same erro appears again.

Comment: Your function editRow() needs to accept one argument. Your onclick is calling editRow() with the row number passed to it...but the function doesn't accept any arguments (hence the error message you're getting)

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me ,please try this

```
    function display(info) {
var table=document.getElementById("table");
var Length=info.length;


    for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++)
    {
        var row = table.insertRow(i+1);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = info[i].firstName;
        cell2.innerHTML = info[i].lastName;

       var editButtonHTML = "<input type=button value=Edit class=edit id=edit-button"+(i+1)+" onclick='editRow("+(i+1)+")'>";

        cell3.innerHTML=editButtonHTML;
    }//end for  
}
```

then next editRow function missed the argument

```
   function editRow(i)
{
    console.log("inside editRow "+(i+1));
}
```